# imap_search with en dash

Tags: php, utf-8, imap

i have a filename which is produced based on the subject line of an email using imap_header(). specifically:

```
$header = imap_header($imap, $m);
$email[$m]['subject'] = imap_utf8($header->subject);
$name = str_replace('/','~~',$email[$m]['subject']) . '[|].txt';  //replace slashes to avoid confusion in filenames 
file_put_contents($name, $contents)
```

in a different script, i process the file, and then I want to find the email based on the subject line and move it to a different email folder.

```
$ffileA = explode('[|]',$ffile);
$subj = $ffileA[0];
$ms = imap_search($imap, 'SUBJECT "'.str_replace('~~','/',$subj).'"');
foreach($ms as $msg){
    imap_mail_move($imap, $msg, 'INBOX/Processed');
}
imap_expunge($imap);
```

this works in almost all cases, but i just came across an email that had =?utf-8?B encoding for the subject (hence the need for imap_utf8($header->subject) ) and had an en dash in the subject line. on the server, the filename has â€“ instead of the en dash, and the imap_search does not find the associated email.
I assume i need to convert this back to a format that imap_search will be able to find. i can probably do that for this single special character using str_replace, but i'd much prefer to be able to handle the general case of similarly weird characters (e.g using iconv() or by replacing the weird character with some type of wildcard or using regex to split the SUBJECT search).

any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

i fixed this as below:

```
$ffileA = explode('[|]',$ffile);
$subj = $ffileA[0];
$ssubj = preg_replace("/[^[:ascii:]]+/",'" SUBJECT "',$subj);
$ms = imap_search($imap, 'SUBJECT "'.str_replace('~~','/',$ssubj).'"');
foreach($ms as $msg){
    imap_mail_move($imap, $msg, 'INBOX/Processed');
}
imap_expunge($imap);
```

this essentially splits the subject search on any non-ASCII substring, so that

```
SUBJECT "abcdefâ€xyz"
```

becomes

```
SUBJECT "abcdef" SUBJECT "xyz"
```

since imap_search has an implicit AND, this is pretty safe, though admittedly a subject 'xyzabcdef' could also match, so it's not entirely without risk